# Show progressbar while task is running in GUI WPF Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, user-interface

I have u full functioning GUI created with WPF Powershell.
Last weeks i saw a lot about runspaces etc. but can't seem to get it working.
Now i want to skip runspaces and use a progressbar when a task is running in the GUI.

Anyone has an example of this and how to implement it?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script/

Comment: That is not what i'm looking @JacobColvin , i'm looking how to implement it in the GUI. Not how to show a progressbar in powershell.